# Making a method asynch

Tags: c#, async-await, bing-api

I have a method that calls the Bing Api.

```
IEnumerable<WebResult> Search(string query)
```

I want to make this asynchronous so that if I make many calls to it, each one of those calls is independant.  So, following the advice [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) I changed the signature to

```
async Task<IEnumerable<WebResult>> SearchAsynch(string query)
```

But I get the warning

```
This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously...
```

I want the entire method to be asynch (at least that's how I think it should work).  How do I do that?  Here's my code

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<WebResult>> SearchAsynch(string query)
        {
            if (query == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("query cannot be null");
            }

            DataServiceQuery<WebResult> webQuery = _bingContainer.Web(query, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            IEnumerable<WebResult> webResults = webQuery.Execute();
            return webResults;
        }
```

The issue is that I'm not sure what to await in this code.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756367.aspx) article would be of assistance?

Comment: +1 for the helpful hint.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `async` keyword doesn't create a new asynchronous operation, it is simply a way of more easily configuring continuations for tasks (i.e. asynchronous operations) that already exist.

In this case, the `DataServiceQuery` class already provides a way to asynchronously execute the query.  Unfortunately it's using the old async model, not the new `Task` based model, so you need to use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to translate it:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<WebResult>> SearchAsynch(string query)
{
    DataServiceQuery<WebResult> webQuery = _bingContainer.Web(query, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(webQuery.BeginExecute(null, null)
        , asyncResult => webQuery.EndExecute(asyncResult)));

}
```

In this particular case since you don't need to do anything other than create the task you don't need `async` or `await` at all, you can just return the task that is constructed.  If you wanted to do something after you got the result you could instead `await` the task:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<WebResult>> SearchAsynch(string query)
{
    DataServiceQuery<WebResult> webQuery = _bingContainer.Web(query, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    var results = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(webQuery.BeginExecute(null, null)
            , asyncResult=> webQuery.EndExecute(asyncResult));
    Console.WriteLine("Hi there");
    return results;
}
```

Comment: With this method do I use the async keyword when calling SearchAsync?

Comment: @SachinKainth You can use it or not; it entirely depends on whether or not you want to, or whether or not it's appropriate in context.  YOu certainly don't *have* to, but you are able to.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really familiar with Bing API, but if the API does not contain async methods, you can make one async by wrapping the calls in a started `Task`. `async` modifier does not make your method automagically asynchronous, it only allows to `await` other async methods inside.

So, in your case, it would probably be the easiest to:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<WebResult>> SearchAsync(string query)
    {
        if (query == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("query cannot be null");
        }

        return Task.Run(() => 
            {
                DataServiceQuery<WebResult> webQuery = _bingContainer.Web(query, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                return webQuery.Execute();
            }
    }
```

Then you can `await` this method in other method marked as `async`:

```
var result = await SearchAsync("yourQuery");
```

If the Bing API has the async method pairs `Begin/End`, you can use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to create task from the async method pairs. Servy's answer goes into more detail there.

Comment: The problem is I will be unit testing this method and those methods are not marked as async

Comment: If you're unit testing and don't want to play with synchronization contexts, you can do a blocking wait. `var taskResult = SearchAsync("query"); Task.Wait(taskResult);`. Then you can access the result by `taskResult.Result`. That *should probably* work...

Comment: Plus I get another error saying "Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Bing.WebResult>' rather than 'Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Bing.WebResult>>'"

Comment: This isn't really proper asynchrony.  You're having a thread pool thread waste all of it's time sitting there doing nothing while you wait on the IO rather than just using the asynchronous querying operation.

Comment: @SachinKainth You need to remove `async` from the method signature, as was done here.

Comment: @Servy Of course, but if you lack the truly asynchronous API on the Bing side, I guess that's the best you can really do...

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor But he *doesn't* lack a truely asynchronous API.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicequery.beginexecute.aspx

Comment: @Servy Oh, OK, I'm not familiar with Bing. Then it's best to use `Task.FromAsync` to convert the `Begin/End` methods to a `Task`, as I mentioned in the very end...

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor You mean [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15888880/1159478) ;)

Comment: @Servy Exactly ;) +1 there.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor I'm not familar with the type at all, I simply Googled the type and found that page.  It's not like it's a special 3rd party tool either.

Comment: @SachinKainth For proper asynchrony, Servy's snippet with `Task.Factory.FromAsync`. In case you ever encounter an API without any kind of asynchronous API, then you can fake asynchrony with what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Per MSDN

> Typically, a method modified by the async keyword contains at least
>   one await expression
>       or statement. The method runs synchronously until it reaches the first await expression,
>       at which point it is suspended until the awaited task is complete. In the meantime, 
>       control is returned to the caller of the method. If the method does not contain an await 
>       expression or statement, then it executes synchronously. A compiler warning alerts you to 
>       any async methods that don't contain await because that situation might indicate an error. 
>       For more information, see Compiler Warning (level 1) CS4014.

EDIT: I figured I would add to this, but it is already in the comment section of this post.  A method marked with `async` doesn't actually run async until it hits a `await` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, this I knew but my issue is that I don't know what to await in my code.

Comment: @SachinKainth The await keyword should be applied to your webQuery.Execute() line and then you return your data.  The await keyword is the actual start of the async operation.  Until then, it is executed synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using async in a stand alone project.

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtMessages = await getMessages2(string sqlConn2, nMessage);
}
public async Task<DataTable> getMessages2(string sqlConn, int n)
{
    //create your query and command
    var o = await cmd2.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    DataTable dtMessages = o;
    return dtMessages;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The warning is just telling you that wherever you are calling SearchAsynch it needs to have await before it.

`var result = await SearchAsynch(query);`

However, the SearchAsynch is not properly implemented as others have stated.

Comment: Well, no that doesn't work because I got the error "The await operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the async modifier"

Comment: He needs to finish properly implementing `SearchAsynch` (which is what this question is asking for help with) before he could ever `await` it.

Comment: The warning specifically states that what he's doing will run synchronously until the await keyword is used. Therefore even if he did implement it correctly and the await keyword was missing it wouldn't be asynchronous. Hardly worth a downvote.

Comment: @KyleC I think you're still missing the point. If he implemented the method correctly, the warning would go away, because it's talking about the code inside the method, not the code that calls the method. How the method is called is another question entirely.